# Why will this only work with break;?

Tags: loops, nested-loops, break

1) Write a program that asks the user to enter the number of pancakes eaten for breakfast by 10 different people (Person 1, Person 2, ..., Person 10).
 Once the data has been entered, the program must analyze the data and output which person ate the most pancakes for breakfast.

My solution uses an array, but the program only displays the person who ate the most sentence if I put a break in the end of the if statement. Without the break the program just asks how much each person ate then exits. I'm just trying to understand exactly why the break needs to be there, or if there is a way to do it without the break.

Here is my code:

```
//Pancakes!
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    //Build array of people and set a value for most eaten
    int people[9] = {};
    int most = -1;


    for (int n=1; n<=10; n++)
    {
        //Sets the number of pancakes eaten to a person value in the array
        cout << "How many pancakes did person " << n << " eat? ";
        cin >> people[n-1];

        //Checks if the value entered above is the highest value
        if(people[n-1] > most)
        {
            most = people[n-1];
        }
    }

    //Line entered for formatting
    cout << endl;

    //Lists the person and how many pancakes they ate
    for (int x=0; x<10; x++)
    {
        if(people[x] == most)
        {
            cout << "Person " << (x+1) << " ate " << most << " pancake(s), the most!" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }




    //Pause after program
    cout << endl;
    std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue...";
    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Also feel free to review my code and give me tips for making it more concise because im still a newbie =] thanks.

Comment: Also, just an FYI im writing this code at work and I cant install a compiler so im compiling online [here](http://www.onlinecompiler.net/) and it doesn't allow the use of ' \n ' so thats why there is a bunch of endl lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above question, I would solve it this way to preview the person who ate the most pancakes:

Code:

```
     // assuming the first one is the highest one
    most = 0;
     //now checking for the higest one

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
      if (people[x] > =people[most]) {
        most = x;
      }
    }

    cout << people[most]; //this shows the highest pancakes.
```

This doesn't use break at all and gives the required output.

Comment: hmm, that's pretty good thanks. I guess I could also make that a function and just call that function at the end. Thanks for the help!